# How to make gettext and poedit recognize custom file types?

Tags: php, smarty, gettext, poedit

I'm trying to get Smarty and gettext to work together in a project of mine. Currently smarty uses `.tpl` files for its template system.
I use PoEdit for creating catalog files and I've added '*.tpl' to the file extensions under PHP but when I try to scan for gettext strings I get the following errors and it is not able to find my strings:

> xgettext: warning: file `../libs/smarty/debug.tpl' extension`tpl' is unknown; will try C
>   xgettext: warning: file `../template/login.tpl' extension`tpl' is unknown; will try C
>   xgettext: warning: file `../template/index.tpl' extension`tpl' is unknown; will try C

Well how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(What you have mentioned should work). Make sure it's saving correctly.

`Edit > Preferences > Parsers`

Select `PHP`

Enter in the allowed extensions...

*.php;*.tpl

[image]

Note: You also might need to update your parser command to include:

`xgettext --language=PHP --force-po -o %o %C %K %F`

Comment: This is not possible since POEDIT version 2. There is no option to edit Parsers.

Comment: @mikep It is, by adding a custom extractor (the "+" button).

Comment: @VáclavSlavík thank you I found it now! But in version Poedit-1.8.13 there is one advantage that I can see extractors setup (xgettext command etc.) for existing languages to get inspired when creating new custom extractor. Eg. for VueJS templates (\*.vue files) I had to use the same options such as for Python (\*.py) but in version 2 I can not see and copy it. Newbie does not know where to start when creating new custom extractor in version 2.

Answer (score 4):

After a day of trying to install smarty parser with no success I have edited the Perl in

> Edit > Preferences > Parsers

So to the list of extensions I added *.tpl

> *.pl;*.tpl

It parses now all {_("text")} inside smarty tpl

Comment: Actually Perl parser didn't work for my html files entirely (had some problems with parsing attributes inside html tags). I found Python parser more accurate - It can parse <input type="text" placeholder="{pgettext('frontend','Your text to translate')}">